# What is the noun form of "succumb"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, nouns

When I am *succumbing* to something, what am I doing?

There are many close synonyms, such as *submission* or *surrender*; however, does *succumb* has its own noun form?

Comment: I thought perhaps *succumbation*, but Googling for that only brings up humorous mentions like this:  http://roussalka.tumblr.com/post/44231629702/succumbation-is-not-a-word-i-would-like-a-refund

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that there is no noun for the act of succumbing. The noun which Sid gives, *succumber*, is the person who does the act, not the act itself (not to mention, the word is not very common).

If you are looking for a noun to use, then it might help to brush up on the [etymology of *succumb*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=succumb). It comes from the Latin verb, *succumbere*, which in its most literal sense means to "lie under".

Ultimately, it depends on what sense of *succumb* you would like to convey. Here are a [few senses of the word:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/succumb)

1. to succumb to strength/force
2. to succumb to temptation/desire
3. to be brought to an end, or to die

I think that *submission* or *surrender* works well for the first sense. The Biblical concept of a Fall works well for the second sense, e.g. *The allure of drugs precipitated his Fall*. Sometimes the result of succumbing is the most appropriate noun form, e.g. *His addiction to drugs*, where addiction is the result. But you wouldn't say *surrender to drugs*, or *submission to drugs*, would you? You might, on the other hand, say *his surrender to temptation started on that day*. As for the last sense (i.e. number three) the words *defeat*, *demise*, and *destruction* come to mind.

In summary, I think the best noun depends on context. But there is no noun form of *succumb*, so you are out of luck there. I would keep in mind the various senses of the word, and maybe even its etymology, when choosing a word.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a little late, but according to the Oxford English Dictionary, the noun of the verb 'to succumb', is succumbency, and used in sentences as succumbence

Comment: Nice!  Do you have a link for reference?